# Show wp_die if url form comment not emply

Tags: php, comments

I removed the url from in comment block, but spammers still post comments and add links. How to rejected comment if url not empty?

Sorry fom My English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all simple operations prior to comment submission use the action [`pre_comment_on_post`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/fb4450a86fe8bc2c0af16910d845323d1b8af47b/wp-includes/comment.php#L3372). Like this:

```
add_action( 'pre_comment_on_post', function() {
    if ( !empty( $_POST['url'] ) ) {
        wp_die( 'Go away!', 'Nope', [ 'response' => 403, 'exit' => true ] );
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. And this is how will be correct  `function()`

Comment: @UserUser-name I fixed the syntax for the function declaration. Should work now, although I haven't tested it.